# local variable assigned to static variable;compile-error in 'c' but successful in c++

Tags: c++, c

Here I tried one program in which local variable **x** is assigned to a static variable **i** and checked whether it assigns value or not.

I did **program in 'C'**: It was obvious that it will give a **compile time error( initializer element is not constant).**

Then I implemented **same program in C++**: and this time **I did not get compile time error**, but output as "equal"(wasn't it supposed to give a compile time error as before).

Please explain this.

```
int main() //C code
{
    int x=10;
    static int i=x;
    if(i==x)
        printf("Equal");
    return 1;
}


int main() //C++ code
{
    int x=10;
    static int i=x;
    if(i==x)
        cout<<"equal";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because C and C++ are different languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike C++, C requires static initializers to be constant. This will not compile in C, but will compile in C++:

```
int makeInitialValue() {
    return 42;
}
static int val = makeInitialValue();
```

This is because C++ inserts special initialization code into your program to be executed before entering `main` for `static` variables outside of functions, or before entering a function for local statics. C does not do that, requiring instead that all `static` initializers be compile-time constants.

**References:**

C99 Standard, 6.7.8

> 4. All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

C++11 Standard, 3.6.2

> Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called *static initialization*; all other initialization is *dynamic initialization*. It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage
>   duration is done before the first statement of main.

Comment: I think the relevant part is that `static` variables in a function are initialized when the function is called for the first time in C++. C initializes them before the program starts.

Comment: Yes.  A cunning plan to confuse C++ developers - a bug in a static c'tor can mean that first line of main is not reached:)